# csv file loop results

Tags: python, file, loops, csv

I'm trying to extract csv files by the cities with `re.findall(), but when I try to do that and write to results to another csv file, it loops over and over many times!

```
import io
import csv
import re

lines=0
outfile1 =codecs.open('/mesh/وسطى.csv','w','utf_8')
outfile6 =codecs.open('/mesh/أخرى.csv','w','utf_8')

with io.open('/mishal.csv','r',encoding="utf-8",newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f :
        for rows in row:
            lines += 1

            #الوسطى
            m = re.findall('\u0634\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621',row)
            if m:
                outfile1.write(row)
            else:
                outfile6.write(row)

print("saved In to mishal !")
f.close()
```

I want the `re.finall()` cities to not loop, just execute once for each match—not loooooooping so many times whenever there's a match.

Here's a screenshot of the output showing the excessive looping:

[image: screenshot of script's output]

Comment: Can you please show examples of input, output and expected output?

Comment: same result for each row loop for like 100 times so each row 100 times looping I don't know how to upload a photo

Comment: I want the file to continue the name number email address for each city I got that but its looping multiple times for each name and number and emails! I hope you get me

Comment: Edit your question to add photos/code.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data.

Answer (score 1):

csv readers return a list for each line of the file - your outer loop is iterating over the lines/rows and your inner loop is iterating over items in each row.  It isn't clear what you want. but your conditional *writes* happen for each item in each row.  If your intent is to check and see if there is a match in the row instead of items in the row,

```
for row in f :
    match = False
    for item in row:
        lines += 1    #??
        #الوسطى   
        match = re.search('\u0634\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621',item)
    if match:
        outfile1.write(row)
    else:
        outfile6.write(row)
```

---

You could accomplish the same thing just iterating over the lines in the file without using a csv reader

```
with io.open('/mishal.csv','r',encoding="utf-8",newline='') as f:
    for line in f:
        #الوسطى
        if re.search('\u0634\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621',line):
            outfile1.write(line)
        else:
            outfile6.write(line)
```

Comment: I could delete this answer, but it really isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: okay let me explain I have a file that contains at least 1500 row and I want to extract a some cities with re. and its workers for me but when I write it out to a csv  file I get loop row for each result like the picture

Comment: Why doesn't my solution work? What is wrong with it? Stating `non of this works for me:(` isn't very helpful.

Comment: its work with the re. and not looping but I get 2 row in 1 row